# Problem with notation in a thesis

Tags: derivatives, notation

I am struggling with section 3.3 of the following thesis https://smartech.gatech.edu/xmlui/bitstream/handle/1853/29610/grigo_alexander_200908_phd.pdf.  Page 21 is fine, then the problems occur in pages 22 and 23 which I believe are mainly down to notation.

"For $\epsilon_0 > 0$ consider a family of $C^5$ function $L_{\epsilon}: U \times U \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ for $|\epsilon|< \epsilon_0$ which satisfy

$ \displaystyle \partial_{\epsilon}\Big|_{\epsilon=0}L_{\epsilon}(s,s_1)=C \frac{s^4+s_1^4}{24}+O_5(s,s_1)$ and $\partial_s \partial_{s_1}L_0(0,0) \neq 0$ for some $C \neq 0$."

What do the $\partial_{\epsilon}$ and $\partial_s \partial_{s_1}$ mean? What do they act on?

Then $L_{ij} := \partial^i_s \partial^j_{s_1}L_0(s,s_1)$. What are $\partial^i_s$ and $\partial^j_{s_1}$, what do $i$ and $j$ correspond to?

In particular on page 23 I cannot see how $\partial_s L_\epsilon(s, S_{\epsilon}(s,y))=y$ and $\partial_{s_1}L_{\epsilon}(s,S_{\epsilon}(s,y))=Y_{\epsilon}(s,y)$ are derived? I seem to be missing some identities used.

Finally, on page 24, I cannot see how $\partial_{\epsilon}\Big|_{\epsilon=0}A_{\epsilon}$ only the third order term $Im c_{21}$? Why is it third order, why arent the other terms third order?

Comment: Yes, this is how I would interpret this notation.

Comment: I would imagine that $\partial_\varepsilon \vert_{\epsilon=0}$ means the (right) partial derivative found by treating the family $L_\varepsilon(s, s_1)$ as a function in three real variables (defined on $[0,\varepsilon_0) \times U \times U$), and differentiating with respect to $\varepsilon$. The other symbols you ask about are just the usual repeated partial derivatives.

Comment: @HTFB but $L_\epsilon$ maps to $\mathbb{R}^2$...

Comment: The point is that you can treat the parameter $\varepsilon$ as another variable, and to define a (right) partial derivative with respect to $\varepsilon$ this must be what is going on. In effect you move the epsilon from a subscript into the variables list, getting a single unified function $ L^\star: [0, \varepsilon) \times U \times U \to \mathbb{R}$, $L^\star:(\varepsilon, s, s_1) \mapsto L_\varepsilon(s, s_1)$

Comment: @HTFB I agree, it's absolutely clear. Problem is that $L_\epsilon: U\times U \to \mathbb{R}^\mathbf{2}$ (it is a vector-valued function). My version: this is a typo. It really must by $L_\epsilon: U\times U \to \mathbb{R}^\mathbf{1}$. Then everything will be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Voliar: I think you are right, at least treating $L_\varepsilon$ as a single-valued function seems consistent(I only gave a quick browse) with everything else on the mentioned pages.